# Routes on Angular and asp mvc controllers does not works

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I've the follow module and route config:

```
var app = angular.module("ApplicationMainModule", ["ngRoute"]);

app.config([
    "$routeProvider", "$locationProvider", function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/showStudents",
        {
            templateUrl: "main/showStudents"
        });            
        $routeProvider.otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: "/"
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix("!");
    }
]);
```

And my controller is this one:

```
public class MainController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ShowStudents()
        {
            return View();
        }    
    }
```

But making the redirection does not works ... Appears this:

[image: Error]

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

Angular routes are the part after the "#" in the URL (e.g. /main#/showStudents), so when you request /showStudents you are still in the MVC side of the routing and it's looking for a controller named ShowStudentsController.

If you want the default route to send you to Main/ShowStudents you'll need to change the routing on the MVC side. You probably have a route setup something like the following:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

Just change the default controller and action to be `Main` and `ShowStudents`.

Answer (score 0):

When using `$locationProvider`, you need to set up a `base` tag somewhere in your markup like this: `<base href="/">`.
Or you can also try, `localhost:PORT/#!/showStudents`, and it should work.